# ORDER BY two fields. Second field (int) orders as varchar problem

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Have been breaking my head over this for 2 hours now, i thought this would be simple. I have a table with a varchar value (task_group) and a int value (task_group_weight). I would like the table sorted by task_group first and by task_group_weight after that.

My Query is:

```
SELECT
    `id`,
    `task_group`,
    `task_group_weight` 
FROM
    `cron` 
WHERE
    `task_group` LIKE 'Imap%' 
ORDER BY
    `task_name`,
    `task_group_weight`;
```

I expect the output to be:

```
|id |task_group | task_group_weight
|1  |imaprunner | 1
|2  |imaprunner | 2
|3  |imaprunner | 10
```

Instead im getting:

```
|id |task_group | task_group_weight
|1  |imaprunner | 1
|2  |imaprunner | 10
|3  |imaprunner | 2
```

So in the second part of the order by it is ordering it like a varchar and not like a int. I already tried the following:

```
  ORDER BY `task_name`,`task_group_weight`+0;
  ORDER BY `task_name`, CAST(`task_group_weight` AS UNSIGNED);
  ORDER BY `task_name`, LPAD(`task_group_weight`,5,0);
```

All with the same result. Hope that someone can give me a quick pointer!

Comment: You use `task_name` column in ORDER BY. You do NOT show the value of this column to us. I think that sorting by its value provides the ordering which you see already (and hence subsequent sorting by `task_group_weight` have no any additional effect).

Answer (score 1):

Ref function [`ABS`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_abs.asp) of mysql

```
ORDER BY task_group, ABS(task_group_weight)
```

You have `task_group` in select & `task_name` in order by. Please check adding `task_group` in order by.

Comment: First off, thank you for the comment. I tried this one but no luck, still getting 1 - 10 - 2 as a sorting on task_group_weight

Comment: @DJQ Please check my edited answer. You have task_name in Order by. May be `1` & `10` having same `task_name` & `2` is having another `task_name`

Comment: You where right.. had not added the task_group but (error from my side) the task_name. The ABS did the trick! You sir are a lifesaver!